# How to make composer update only files in composer.lock/json and not pull new versions

Tags: php, git, composer-php

We are keeping the composer.json/composer.lock in our repository and using composer to update the dependencies.  We have a githook for post-checkout to do a composer update.  If there is a new version of one of our dependencies or dependencies dependencies it will download the update and change the composer.lock

The problem is that I don't want this because I'll have two developers committing the lock files and there will be needless conflicts.

What I would like is to have the composer update be a manual process, commit the composer.lock with the specific versions, and have composer update only based on what has changed in the composer.lock.  But I don't see how to do that (and maybe I'm misunderstanding - and it doesn't work that way..)

Is there a way to do this, or another way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your hook to `composer install`, which will read from the lock file on checkout. Then also add a `post-merge` hook to do the same, such that if one person commits changes to `composer.lock` the merged version will automatically install and/or update as necessary.

General rule is that `install` uses `.lock` if it exists, `update` always just uses `.json`.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to (almost) do this.
https://gist.github.com/yehosef/8ffbab1f2dbbef22b757

```
#!/bin/bash
OLD=`md5 -q composer.lock.old`
NEW=`md5 -q composer.lock`
if [ "$NEW" != "$OLD" ]
then
  php composer.phar  update
fi
cat composer.lock > composer.lock.old
```

I run this in the post-checkout git hook.  I commit the composer.lock and .gitignore the composer.lock.old.  When I want to do an update, I do it manually with composer update and then commit the composer.lock.

The problem is that this is not directly matching the versions to the what's in the composer.lock - just keeping me from doing composer updates all the time.

Still would be better to force composer to only load the specific versions in composer.lock.